# Why my css media queries are not working?

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

I am a new coder(14-year-old) and for now, I am learning web development, I am telling you this because I don't know any "tech-words or complicated words" so please answer in simple language.


#### Question:


I am writing this media query:

```
@media only for screen (max-width: 400px; ) {
     #box1 {
         font-size: 4em;
         color: white;
         border-left: 3em solid yellow;
     }
}
```

And the results are not showing up,
So could you please tell me, is there any mistakes in the code? or is it something else

I am using Google Chrome as the browser and Microsoft visual studio code as code editor

Comment: This media query takes effect when the screen is smaller than 400px. Do you use a screen smaller than 400px?

Comment: If you mean to target screens larger than 400px use 'min-width' instead of max-width

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you, but sometimes, you just need to clear cache in order for the CSS  to load again.
To clear cache:
On your computer, open Chrome.
At the top right, click More .
Click More tools. Clear browsing data.
Next to "Cookies and other site data" and "Cached images and files," check the boxes.
Click Clear data.

Hope it was helpfull

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px; ) {
/*whatever code is in here*/
}
```

Comment: you forgot the and

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
w3schools is a good resource for beginners :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try using**

```
 @media (max-width: 400px) {
        #box1 {
            font-size: 4em;
            color: white;
            border-left: 3em solid yellow;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** This will work for all screens having `width < and = 400px`